# Amazon EC2 EBS automatic backup one-liner works manually but not from cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, backup

I am trying to implement an automatic backup system for my EBS on Amazon AWS.

When I run this command as `ec2-user`:

```
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-********
```

everything works fine.

But if I add this line into `/etc/crontab` and restart the `crond` service:

```
15 12 * * * ec2-user /opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-********
```

that doesn't work.

I checked `var/log/cron` and there is this line, therefore the command gets executed:

```
Dec 13 12:15:01 ip-10-204-111-94 CROND[4201]: (ec2-user) CMD (/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-******** )
```

Can you please help me to troubleshoot the problem?

I guess is some environment problem - maybe the lack of some variable. If that's the case I don't know what to do about it.

Thanks.

Comment: cron might be running under a different user/group, having no access to your credential configurations

Comment: Hi Guy. I don't think that's the problem. Both on the command line and crontab, I use ec2-user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters crontab does not have $PATH and you will also have to have EC2_HOME and JAVA_HOME  exported.
I suggest that you make a script that has the two exports on the top and then you call the create snapshot.
So a simple

```
export EC2_HOME=your_ec2_home
export JAVA_HOME=your_java_home
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-********
```

As a rule of thumb it is generally a good practice to have your backup procedure in a script.
You can find a sample script in the following link:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=350163.
There are a number of scripts available that are customizable and have most of ec2 functionality automated.

Answer (score 9):

You should consider taking advantage of AWS's new [IAM Roles](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/WorkingWithRoles.html) functionality.  Essentially what you do is create a new role in the IAM control panel and then assign it rights to create snapshots.  The policy you would need to attach to the role would look something like this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1355446824880",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you create your instance, you define the IAM role in the launch configuration (it's under "advanced settings").  The effect is that your instance now automatically has permission to create snapshots and you don't have to worry about storing the access keys or other credentials anywhere on the instance.  It will work via cron without issue.

Comment: Interesting - I was considering to use IAM. It seems I need to recreate the instance from what you are saying. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you would.  Ideally instances should be stateless (contain no persistent data), so this wouldn't be an issue.  But if you're in a different situation, you could always package your existing config as a new AMI and relaunch it, but with an IAM role attached.

Comment: Is there a way I can keep everything as it is? Why is my solution not working?

Comment: Using x509 certs for authentication is deprecated and will likely be going away.  You're better off using AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variables.  But then you have to embed the keys in the AMI which is strongly discouraged.  That's why using an AMI role is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

The cron log shows that cron is executing the command, but it is having no apparent effect. You know that the ec2-user can run the command from the shell. So first make sure that root can run this command successfully from the shell:

```
sudo bash
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-********
```

If this doesn't work then the problem isn't with cron, it's with differences between the ec2-user and root accounts. I suppose that could be permissions based, but root is very powerful. It may be due to their different environments.

When you run the command as ec2-user you may have the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variables set to valid values. In that case the ec2 command line tool may be using them and ignoring the -K and -C options. The credentials specified using -K and -C may not be valid but you wouldn't know that because they are being ignored. The root account has a different environment, presumably without valid values for those variables.

This might happen because the use of certificates (the -K and -C options) instead of access keys has been deprecated by Amazon. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html#set-aws-credentials.

You can try to test this theory by seeing if those variables are set when you run the command from the console:

```
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
echo $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

If they show values, this is probably the reason for the difference.

Another thing to try is to replace the command with one with valid access keys instead of a certificate (the -O and -W parameters instead of -K and -C). You can create a user via IAM that can only do the operation you want, and use its credentials for the command.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. However, I am not running the command root, neither via the command line, nor via cron.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to export more variables, to be the same as in ec2-user environment.

I defined a new script ec2-backup.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
export EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=...
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=...
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
/home/ec2-user/aws-missing-tools-master/ec2-automate-backup/ec2-automate-backup.sh -v 'all volumes ' -n -r eu-west-1 -p -k 2
```

And then execute this script from my cronjob. Sending the job output to a log file was extremely helpful for debugging:

```
0 0 * * * /home/ec2-user/ec2-backup.sh >> /home/ec2-user/cronoutput.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The CRON Env uses a reduced environement setting. So not all environement variables are set here. We had the same issue with a cronjob, that was lacking some envvars.

**What we did not want, was to create a script to export elements**, but instead to source the existing environment variables, as this seemed less prone to errors in case the configuration changed.

I found my solution (well hidden in the last anstwer) here:
[AWS Help](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116826)

The env vars for AWS EBS are stored in a file under: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars`. So sourcing or reading this file did the trick for me. In a root crontab this could look like this:

```
30 2 * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && php /var/www/bin/some_command.php
```

Like this, you:

- only maintain your env vars in one place (your choice)
- can use them wherever you need them
- always use the same env vars

Answer (score -1):

Try to capture the stdout/stderr :

1) Move the command to a shell script and invoke the shell command from cron, eg

```
15 12 * * * /home/someuser/some_script.sh >/home/someuser/some_script.cronoutput 2>&1
```

2) Contents of some_script.sh ; make sure the execute bit is set

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot --region us-east-1 -K /home/ec2-user/pk.pem -C /home/ec2-user/cert.pem -d "vol-******** snapshot" vol-********
```